# Need html help displaying multiple rows under one unique selected ID

Tags: css, html-table, selection, stylesheet, tablerow

I have this table where I am trying to display two rows based on a single id but only col-1 and col-2 show based on drop down selection.  col-3 & col-4 never disappear.  I know it's not the best practice to use a unique id multiple times in one document that's why I have all my "td" under the one "tr" with a unique ID,  I am struggling to figure out why the "inv"  class only applies to first row or first two "td"

Any clues why?

```
    <style>
    .inv {
        display: none;
    }
        </style>

    <table class="blueTable">
<select id="target">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
</select>
    <tbody>

        <tr id="CA" class="inv">
         <td>
            col-1
         </td>
         <td>
            Col-2
         </td>
         <td>
            col-3
         </td>
         <td>
            col-4
         </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
<script>
            document
                .getElementById('target')
                .addEventListener('change', function () {
                    'use strict';
                    var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),   
                        target = document.getElementById(this.value); // get the option id selected
                    if (vis !== null) { // reset the vis tag state
                        vis.className = 'inv';
                    }
                    if (target !== null ) {// if target not null then set the target link to visable state
                        target.className = 'vis';
                    }
            });
</script>
```

> Here is the css code

```
 table.blueTable {


font-family: Georgia, serif;
  border: 1px solid #1C6EA4;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.blueTable td, table.blueTable th {
  border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
  padding: 3px 2px;
}
table.blueTable tbody td {
  font-size: 12px;
}
table.blueTable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #D0E4F5;
}
table.blueTable thead {
  background: #1C6EA4;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #9C9C9C;
}
table.blueTable thead th {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-left: 2px solid #D0E4F5;
}
table.blueTable thead th:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

table.blueTable tfoot td {
  font-size: 14px;
}
table.blueTable tfoot .links {
  text-align: right;
}
table.blueTable tfoot .links a{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #1C6EA4;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: What are you excatly trying to do? Make them visible ? or hidden?

To make them visible, just remove display:none from inv class.

Comment: I am trying to make specific rows appear based on a drop down selection

Answer (score 0):

There are some good on web technologies on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/default.asp). So there were some changes needed in your JavaScript. I was not sure what exactly you were trying to do. But if you add the below code

Change your JS:

```
document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('change', function () {
target = this; // get the option id selected
if (target !== null ) {  
//depending on opyion selected, use its value to get the
//table/tr you want to display                                          
document.getElementById(this.value).className = "vis";
}});
```

In your CSS add:

```
.vis{
  display: block;
}
```

Also look at this JSFiddle which is working:[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lenz1a50/11/)

Comment: Thakns but  there are two issues with that
1-  all columns appear on one single row as opposed to each column on a new row
2- I want to make sure that the grid gets reset every time user selects a new state from the drop down